# South thinks all my fields have blank=True

Tags: django, django-south

I've just added a new field and run `schemamigration app --auto` The migration generated adds my new field but also adds blank=True for what looks like every field which isn't a primary key.

The only thing I can think of that might have changed is that I've recently [split my models into multiple files](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookSplitModelsToFiles). I think that change happened before the last migration, not before this broken one though.

Can I solve this issue and recreate the migration?

What would happen if I just removed all the lines from `forward` and `backward` that don't relate to the new field I'm adding?

---

**Here's an example field:**

From my last migration:

```
# from models object
'as_admin': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
```

From this one:

```
# Forward migration
db.alter_column('groups_invite', 'as_admin', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(blank=True))

# models object
'as_admin': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False', 'blank': 'True'}),
```

From the model, as it is now and always has been:

```
as_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: This has just happened to me too - did you get an answer from anywhere?

Comment: I just let it run with blank=True since it doesn't affect the database at all. (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank) It's only used validation in admin and forms and they will look at the models not the migrations anyway.